# lxc-start: utils.c: safe_mount: 1746 No such file or directory - Failed to mount /lib64 onto /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/lxc/lib64

Tags: linux, ubuntu-14.04, lxc, lxc-docker

I was trying to run cross-compiled lxc image on another machine as followings:
I **created an lxc image** on a ubuntu 14.04 via command:

```
lxc-create -t /usr/share/lxc/templates/lxc-busybox -n customBusyBox
```

I checked it that the created image **customBusyBox** was running fine on this machine. Now I created its **.tar.gz** file i.e **customBusyBox.tar.gz** and **copy it on another** machine having same version of ubuntu i.e 14.04 via **scp** command.
where then I extracted customBusyBox image to **/var/lib/lxc** folder.
Then as super user I tried to **run the image** via following command:

```
lxc-start -F -n customBusyBox
```

Then I got this error:

```
lxc-start: utils.c: safe_mount: 1746 No such file or directory - Failed to mount /lib64 onto /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/lxc/lib64
                                                                                                                              lxc-start: conf.c: mount_entry: 1650 No such file or directory - failed to mount '/lib64' on '/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/lxc/lib64'
                                                         lxc-start: conf.c: lxc_setup: 3790 failed to setup the mount entries for 'openWrt'
                                                                                                                                           lxc-start: start.c: do_start: 826 Failed to setup container "openWrt".
            lxc-start: sync.c: __sync_wait: 57 An error occurred in another process (expected sequence number 3)
                                                                                                                lxc-start: start.c: __lxc_start: 1338 Failed to spawn container "openWrt".
                                                                                                                                                                                          lxc-start: tools/lxc_start.c: main: 360 The container failed to start.
lxc-start: tools/lxc_start.c: main: 364 Additional information can be obtained by setting the --logfile and --logpriority options.
```

I tried searching for its solution on net but no help:
Someone please suggest some solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this error.

Following was the config file of created **customBusyBox** container, on first host machine:

```
# Template used to create this container: /usr/share/lxc/templates/lxc-busybox
# Parameters passed to the template:
# For additional config options, please look at lxc.container.conf(5)
lxc.network.type = veth
lxc.network.flags = up
lxc.network.link = lxcbr0
lxc.network.hwaddr = 00:16:3e:1d:e5:8c
lxc.rootfs = /var/lib/lxc/OpenWrt/rootfs
lxc.haltsignal = SIGUSR1
lxc.utsname = OpenWrt
lxc.tty = 1
lxc.pts = 1
lxc.cap.drop = sys_module mac_admin mac_override sys_time

# When using LXC with apparmor, uncomment the next line to run unconfined:
#lxc.aa_profile = unconfined
lxc.mount.entry = /lib lib none ro,bind 0 0
lxc.mount.entry = /usr/lib usr/lib none ro,bind 0 0
lxc.mount.entry = /lib64 lib64 none ro,bind 0 0
lxc.mount.entry = /usr/lib64 usr/lib64 none ro,bind 0 0
lxc.mount.entry = /sys/kernel/security sys/kernel/security none ro,bind,optional 0 0
lxc.mount.auto = proc:mixed sys
```

---

I **removed** the following lines from the above config file on another host machine:

```
lxc.mount.entry = /lib64 lib64 none ro,bind 0 0
lxc.mount.entry = /usr/lib64 usr/lib64 none ro,bind 0 0
```

Then I tried and it ran successfully there also. Actually there was **not** any such directory i.e **/lib64 or /usr/lib64** **present** on this second host machine that's why there was a mount error coming for these directories.

config file is present at path : `/var/lib/lxc/<container-name>/`